# switch to running activity when notification clicked in android/Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am showing notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder`. I want when user clicked on the notification, it will switch to the running activity and not the activity that is fixed.

Suppose I am having 4 activities, I am on 2nd activity and show some notification to the user and moved to 4th activity and then pressed the home button. Now the notification is still there. When user clicked to that, it should moved to the 4th activity.

How to detect that? Here's the code I had done so far.

```
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 0)
                         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                         .SetContentTitle(Title)
                         .SetContentText(messageBody)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true)
                          .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: Why do you want notification click twice?

Comment: @K K. I didn't mentioned twice

Comment: Can you elaborate more then

Comment: It short: I want to resume my app from notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, Just I need to replace the `PendingIntent`. Here's the full code

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

//var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 0)
                         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                         .SetContentTitle(Title)
                         .SetContentText(messageBody)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true)
                          .SetContentIntent(GetRunningIntent());

var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());



 PendingIntent GetRunningIntent()
            {
                var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(PackageName)
                    .SetPackage(null)
                    .SetFlags(ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, 0);
                return pendingIntent;
            }
```